# Toggle radio button on Mobile angular UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

i'm tryng to put two radio button on my registration form on a Mobile Angular UI based application but i run into two problems:

-on a normal bootstrap-angular based app the selection of one radio change the visual active status but in my case no

-on chrome i've the following problem:

```
 target' or 'target-class' attribute required with 'toggle' 
 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
```

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/187jab3k/

thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
   <button type="button" ng-model="gender" ng-click="color = 'mr';" class="btn btn-default">MR.
   </button>
   <button type="button" ng-model="gender" ng-click="color = 'mrs';" class="btn btn-default">MRS.
   </button>
</div>
<label>{{gender}}</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this was down-voted... it's a short-coming in [mobile-angular-ui](https://github.com/mcasimir/mobile-angular-ui). It also lacks any slider control you need on mobile.

I used some buttons to simulate the radio behaviour:

```
  <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <label>Urgency:</label>
      <input type="hidden" ng-model="model.urgency">
      <button type="button" ng-click="model.urgency=0;" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-primary': !model.urgency}">None</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="model.urgency=1;" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-primary': model.urgency==1}">Low</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="model.urgency=2;" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-primary': model.urgency==2}">Medium</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="model.urgency=3;" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-primary': model.urgency==3}">High</button>
    </div>
```

Hope that helps someone... :~